# HTML select options Show in Wrong Position After Moved

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using `<select>` with options for changing the axes on a graph in d3.  The drop down menu is positioned by using the css rule transform.  The css is applied to a parent container (div).  The div with the `<select>` is positioned as intended; however, once it is expanded, the options show in different places between Chrome (shows at the bottom edge), Firefox (shows at the original place of the `<select>`, and Edge(shows at the top edge).

HTML (the chart and other HTML left out for brevity as I am only concerned about the drop down menu):

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/weeser/vdp0rz5w/

SNIPPET:

```css
#chyDrop {
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(127px) translateY(-350px);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(127px) translateY(-350px);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(127px) translateY(-350px);
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(127px) translateY(-350px);
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="chyDrop">
  <!-- some qtip help tips go here -->
  <select id="chyDrop_select">
    <option value="Effect">Effect Size</option>
    <option value="NormGain">Normalized Gain</option>
    <option value="RawGain">Raw Gain</option>
    <option value="Score">Score</option>
    <option value="ScoreMatched">Score (matched)</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

I prefer how the options are positioned in Chrome, but have been unable to figure out why it behaves differently in the other browsers or add css (have tried changing the position, left, and top styles) that makes it consistent.  Any help in explaining why this happens and how to make the options appear in a consistent position would help greatly.

Comment: For this case I would use a jquery plugin to help me stylize the select tag the way I want. The idea behind this is simple, the original select becomes hidden by the plugin and is replaced by markup which you can stylize with css. For example see [http://hernansartorio.com/jquery-nice-select/](http://hernansartorio.com/jquery-nice-select/)

Comment: @antithesis Thanks!  This helped.  I was able to get the behavior/styles using jquery UI.  Hopefully <options> in the future will become more css friendly.